# Adding difficulty levels into Java Chess Game

Tags: java, chess, levels

I am currently working on developing a Java Chess Game and have the game up and running correctly. But I want to add a function at the start where the user is able to select which difficulty they want to play at. I would like to add 3 difficulties, (Easy, Medium, Hard). At the moment, I already have a pop up function at the start asking the user if they or the computer wants to start the game. Thanks.

The code is below:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Chess {
    static String chessBoard[][]={
        {"r","k","b","q","a","b","k","r"},
        {"p","p","p","p","p","p","p","p"},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {" "," "," "," "," "," "," "," "},
        {"P","P","P","P","P","P","P","P"},
        {"R","K","B","Q","A","B","K","R"}};
    static int kingPositionC, kingPositionL;
    static int humanAsWhite=-1;//1=human as white, 0=human as black
    static int globalDepth=4;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (!"A".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8][kingPositionC%8])) {kingPositionC++;}//get King's location
        while (!"a".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionL/8][kingPositionL%8])) {kingPositionL++;}//get king's location
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Chess Tutorial");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        UserInterface ui=new UserInterface();
        f.add(ui);
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println(sortMoves(posibleMoves()));
        Object[] option={"Computer","Human"};
        humanAsWhite=JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Who should play as white?", "ABC Options", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, option, option[1]);
        if (humanAsWhite==0) {
            long startTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            makeMove(alphaBeta(globalDepth, 1000000, -1000000, "", 0));
            long endTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("That took "+(endTime-startTime)+" milliseconds");
            flipBoard();
            f.repaint();
        }
        makeMove("7655 ");
        undoMove("7655 ");
        for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(chessBoard[i]));
        }
    }
    public static String alphaBeta(int depth, int beta, int alpha, String move, int player) {
        //return in the form of 1234b##########
        String list=posibleMoves();
        if (depth==0 || list.length()==0) {return move+(Rating.rating(list.length(), depth)*(player*2-1));}
        list=sortMoves(list);
        player=1-player;//either 1 or 0
        for (int i=0;i<list.length();i+=5) {
            makeMove(list.substring(i,i+5));
            flipBoard();
            String returnString=alphaBeta(depth-1, beta, alpha, list.substring(i,i+5), player);
            int value=Integer.valueOf(returnString.substring(5));
            flipBoard();
            undoMove(list.substring(i,i+5));
            if (player==0) {
                if (value<=beta) {beta=value; if (depth==globalDepth) {move=returnString.substring(0,5);}}
            } else {
                if (value>alpha) {alpha=value; if (depth==globalDepth) {move=returnString.substring(0,5);}}
            }
            if (alpha>=beta) {
                if (player==0) {return move+beta;} else {return move+alpha;}
            }
        }
        if (player==0) {return move+beta;} else {return move+alpha;}
    }
    public static void flipBoard() {
        String temp;
        for (int i=0;i<32;i++) {
            int r=i/8, c=i%8;
            if (Character.isUpperCase(chessBoard[r][c].charAt(0))) {
                temp=chessBoard[r][c].toLowerCase();
            } else {
                temp=chessBoard[r][c].toUpperCase();
            }
            if (Character.isUpperCase(chessBoard[7-r][7-c].charAt(0))) {
                chessBoard[r][c]=chessBoard[7-r][7-c].toLowerCase();
            } else {
                chessBoard[r][c]=chessBoard[7-r][7-c].toUpperCase();
            }
            chessBoard[7-r][7-c]=temp;
        }
        int kingTemp=kingPositionC;
        kingPositionC=63-kingPositionL;
        kingPositionL=63-kingTemp;
    }
    public static void makeMove(String move) {
        if (move.charAt(4)!='P') {
            chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(2))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3))]=chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))];
            chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))]=" ";
            if ("A".equals(chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(2))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3))])) {
                kingPositionC=8*Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(2))+Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3));
            }
        } else {
            //if pawn promotion
            chessBoard[1][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))]=" ";
            chessBoard[0][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))]=String.valueOf(move.charAt(3));
        }
    }
    public static void undoMove(String move) {
        if (move.charAt(4)!='P') {
            chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))]=chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(2))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3))];
            chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(2))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(3))]=String.valueOf(move.charAt(4));
            if ("A".equals(chessBoard[Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))])) {
                kingPositionC=8*Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))+Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1));
            }
        } else {
            //if pawn promotion
            chessBoard[1][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(0))]="P";
            chessBoard[0][Character.getNumericValue(move.charAt(1))]=String.valueOf(move.charAt(2));
        }
    }
    public static String posibleMoves() {
        String list="";
        for (int i=0; i<64; i++) {
            switch (chessBoard[i/8][i%8]) {
                case "P": list+=posibleP(i);
                    break;
                case "R": list+=posibleR(i);
                    break;
                case "K": list+=posibleK(i);
                    break;
                case "B": list+=posibleB(i);
                    break;
                case "Q": list+=posibleQ(i);
                    break;
                case "A": list+=posibleA(i);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return list;//x1,y1,x2,y2,captured piece
    }
    public static String posibleP(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
            try {//capture
                if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r-1][c+j].charAt(0)) && i>=16) {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r-1][c+j];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r-1][c+j]="P";
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        list=list+r+c+(r-1)+(c+j)+oldPiece;
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="P";
                    chessBoard[r-1][c+j]=oldPiece;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            try {//promotion && capture
                if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r-1][c+j].charAt(0)) && i<16) {
                    String[] temp={"Q","R","B","K"};
                    for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r-1][c+j];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r-1][c+j]=temp[k];
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            //column1,column2,captured-piece,new-piece,P
                            list=list+c+(c+j)+oldPiece+temp[k]+"P";
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="P";
                        chessBoard[r-1][c+j]=oldPiece;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        try {//move one up
            if (" ".equals(chessBoard[r-1][c]) && i>=16) {
                oldPiece=chessBoard[r-1][c];
                chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                chessBoard[r-1][c]="P";
                if (kingSafe()) {
                    list=list+r+c+(r-1)+c+oldPiece;
                }
                chessBoard[r][c]="P";
                chessBoard[r-1][c]=oldPiece;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        try {//promotion && no capture
            if (" ".equals(chessBoard[r-1][c]) && i<16) {
                String[] temp={"Q","R","B","K"};
                for (int k=0; k<4; k++) {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r-1][c];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r-1][c]=temp[k];
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        //column1,column2,captured-piece,new-piece,P
                        list=list+c+c+oldPiece+temp[k]+"P";
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="P";
                    chessBoard[r-1][c]=oldPiece;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        try {//move two up
            if (" ".equals(chessBoard[r-1][c]) && " ".equals(chessBoard[r-2][c]) && i>=48) {
                oldPiece=chessBoard[r-2][c];
                chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                chessBoard[r-2][c]="P";
                if (kingSafe()) {
                    list=list+r+c+(r-2)+c+oldPiece;
                }
                chessBoard[r][c]="P";
                chessBoard[r-2][c]=oldPiece;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return list;
    }
    public static String posibleR(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        int temp=1;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
            try {
                while(" ".equals(chessBoard[r][c+temp*j]))
                {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r][c+temp*j];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r][c+temp*j]="R";
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        list=list+r+c+r+(c+temp*j)+oldPiece;
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="R";
                    chessBoard[r][c+temp*j]=oldPiece;
                    temp++;
                }
                if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r][c+temp*j].charAt(0))) {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r][c+temp*j];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r][c+temp*j]="R";
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        list=list+r+c+r+(c+temp*j)+oldPiece;
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="R";
                    chessBoard[r][c+temp*j]=oldPiece;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            temp=1;
            try {
                while(" ".equals(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c]))
                {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r+temp*j][c]="R";
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+c+oldPiece;
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="R";
                    chessBoard[r+temp*j][c]=oldPiece;
                    temp++;
                }
                if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c].charAt(0))) {
                    oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c];
                    chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                    chessBoard[r+temp*j][c]="R";
                    if (kingSafe()) {
                        list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+c+oldPiece;
                    }
                    chessBoard[r][c]="R";
                    chessBoard[r+temp*j][c]=oldPiece;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            temp=1;
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static String posibleK(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
            for (int k=-1; k<=1; k+=2) {
                try {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2].charAt(0)) || " ".equals(chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2])) {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+j)+(c+k*2)+oldPiece;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="K";
                        chessBoard[r+j][c+k*2]=oldPiece;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                try {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k].charAt(0)) || " ".equals(chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k])) {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+j*2)+(c+k)+oldPiece;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="K";
                        chessBoard[r+j*2][c+k]=oldPiece;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static String posibleB(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        int temp=1;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
            for (int k=-1; k<=1; k+=2) {
                try {
                    while(" ".equals(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]))
                    {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]="B";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+(c+temp*k)+oldPiece;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="B";
                        chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]=oldPiece;
                        temp++;
                    }
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k].charAt(0))) {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]="B";
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+(c+temp*k)+oldPiece;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="B";
                        chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]=oldPiece;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                temp=1;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static String posibleQ(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        int temp=1;
        for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
            for (int k=-1; k<=1; k++) {
                if (j!=0 || k!=0) {
                    try {
                        while(" ".equals(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]))
                        {
                            oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k];
                            chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                            chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]="Q";
                            if (kingSafe()) {
                                list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+(c+temp*k)+oldPiece;
                            }
                            chessBoard[r][c]="Q";
                            chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]=oldPiece;
                            temp++;
                        }
                        if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k].charAt(0))) {
                            oldPiece=chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k];
                            chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                            chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]="Q";
                            if (kingSafe()) {
                                list=list+r+c+(r+temp*j)+(c+temp*k)+oldPiece;
                            }
                            chessBoard[r][c]="Q";
                            chessBoard[r+temp*j][c+temp*k]=oldPiece;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    temp=1;
                }
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
    public static String posibleA(int i) {
        String list="", oldPiece;
        int r=i/8, c=i%8;
        for (int j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if (j!=4) {
                try {
                    if (Character.isLowerCase(chessBoard[r-1+j/3][c-1+j%3].charAt(0)) || " ".equals(chessBoard[r-1+j/3][c-1+j%3])) {
                        oldPiece=chessBoard[r-1+j/3][c-1+j%3];
                        chessBoard[r][c]=" ";
                        chessBoard[r-1+j/3][c-1+j%3]="A";
                        int kingTemp=kingPositionC;
                        kingPositionC=i+(j/3)*8+j%3-9;
                        if (kingSafe()) {
                            list=list+r+c+(r-1+j/3)+(c-1+j%3)+oldPiece;
                        }
                        chessBoard[r][c]="A";
                        chessBoard[r-1+j/3][c-1+j%3]=oldPiece;
                        kingPositionC=kingTemp;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        //need to add casting later
        return list;
    }
    public static String sortMoves(String list) {
        int[] score=new int [list.length()/5];
        for (int i=0;i<list.length();i+=5) {
            makeMove(list.substring(i, i+5));
            score[i/5]=-Rating.rating(-1, 0);
            undoMove(list.substring(i, i+5));
        }
        String newListA="", newListB=list;
        for (int i=0;i<Math.min(6, list.length()/5);i++) {//first few moves only
            int max=-1000000, maxLocation=0;
            for (int j=0;j<list.length()/5;j++) {
                if (score[j]>max) {max=score[j]; maxLocation=j;}
            }
            score[maxLocation]=-1000000;
            newListA+=list.substring(maxLocation*5,maxLocation*5+5);
            newListB=newListB.replace(list.substring(maxLocation*5,maxLocation*5+5), "");
        }
        return newListA+newListB;
    }
    public static boolean kingSafe() {
        //bishop/queen
        int temp=1;
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i+=2) {
            for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
                try {
                    while(" ".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8+temp*j])) {temp++;}
                    if ("b".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8+temp*j]) ||
                            "q".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8+temp*j])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                temp=1;
            }
        }
        //rook/queen
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i+=2) {
            try {
                while(" ".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8][kingPositionC%8+temp*i])) {temp++;}
                if ("r".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8][kingPositionC%8+temp*i]) ||
                        "q".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8][kingPositionC%8+temp*i])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            temp=1;
            try {
                while(" ".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8])) {temp++;}
                if ("r".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8]) ||
                        "q".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+temp*i][kingPositionC%8])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            temp=1;
        }
        //knight
        for (int i=-1; i<=1; i+=2) {
            for (int j=-1; j<=1; j+=2) {
                try {
                    if ("k".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+i][kingPositionC%8+j*2])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
                try {
                    if ("k".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+i*2][kingPositionC%8+j])) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
        //pawn
        if (kingPositionC>=16) {
            try {
                if ("p".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8-1][kingPositionC%8-1])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            try {
                if ("p".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8-1][kingPositionC%8+1])) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            //king
            for (int i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
                for (int j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
                    if (i!=0 || j!=0) {
                        try {
                            if ("a".equals(chessBoard[kingPositionC/8+i][kingPositionC%8+j])) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How exactly do you want to make the game harder?

Comment: So wait, are you asking us how to create a chess AI? That's not exactly a trivial problem. (Also, on an unrelated note, your code looks like it'd be a complete nightmare to read, write or maintain. OOP is your friend.)

Comment: The game could be made harder by for example, on easy, the system makes moves which u can easily counteract, or if you are playing hard, the system makes really smart moves which are very hard to play against.

Comment: No I am not asking you to create a chess AI. I am just asking how would I add difficulty levels into my already created chess game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: please only show relevant code.

Other than that the answer is pretty simple. I suppose you want to implement several AI strategies and have the player choose which one to use. Have a class `ComputerPlayer` and give it a constructor `public ComputerPlayer(Strategy s)`. This will determine which strategy to use, so store that as an instance variable. This should then call `s.determineMove()` or whatever you decide to name the method to do just that: determine the move.

Then create an Interface `Strategy` and have several strategies (in this case: easy, medium, hard) implement this.

If you have no idea what I'm talking about, you're probably not ready to implement an AI anyway.

Also I'd like to suggest looking at the very least at the [MVC-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Comment: In that case, please consider tagging this as the correct answer (the check), for potential future viewers (that is, if this is your chosen answer).